# Can I install Oracle 12c and NOT use pluggable databases?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I've just installed Oracle 12c.   I did not select any of the fancy new options, I just wanted an Oracle instance.   I'm fairly new to Oracle but I was used to 11.2.0.4.

Every command I try now fails and it's always something like "Cannot do [x] on pluggable database", etc.

I just want a normal oracle instance and I want to be able to create users and import my database but every turn I take has some frustrating error having to do with pluggable databases.  I don't care at all about them, and I specifically tried to avoid any install option that looked like it would make a "pluggable" database but apparently it still did.

Is there any way I can just keep life the same in 12c or am I stuck with this entirely clumsy pluggable paradigm?
Thanks very much.

Comment: Who moved my cheese?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to use single tenant..
here you go --> [Single Tenant Configuration](https://blogs.oracle.com/Multitenant/entry/single_tenant_configuration)

Comment: Oracle will Non-CDB's desupport it in future (desupport means, single-tenant deployment (a CDB with one PDB - no Multitenant license required)  [more](https://blogs.oracle.com/UPGRADE/entry/non_cdb_architecture_of_oracle)  but not set in stone ;)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is. Just create a Non-CDB (the old architecture) database, but keep in mind this architecture will be deprecated in the future.

Comment: This doesn't offer any more information than Tesla & Patrick's Answer/Comment.

Comment: @JohnM comments may be deleted at any time, without notice. I know almost nothing about Oracle's pluggable databases, or single-tenant architecture or non-CDB databases but it seems this answer has some value. The other answer is also just a link. Is this answer really worth a -3 while the other a +2?

Comment: Information that is useful for the question should be in answer, not comments. Whether the specific fact about the deprecation is good enough for a separate answer or it should be an edit to the other answer, I won't judge but the answer shouldn't be downvoted just because the info is in a comment - that some readers may just miss reading. The down or up vote should be on whether the answer adds something to the question asked.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Fair point. I'd un-vote if I could at this point, but it is locked.